# Как задать маску вида 0x55555555 переносимым образом?

Tags: c++, c, битовые-операции

В некоторых задачах связанных с манипуляцией битами нужна маска для всех чётных битов. Каждый раз такая маска задаётся константой вида 0x55555555, что хорошо если `unsigned` занимает 32 бита. А если 16 или 64?

Как определить маску для всех чётных битов способом, который будет работать для любого числа бит в типе? Определение должно быть константой времени компиляции.

Comment: для Си пользуюсь обычно двойной компиляцией. `gcc makemask.c && a.out > mask.h` так сойдёт?

Comment: @AlexGlebe, пока нет лучших вариантов, сойдёт.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Можно просто `(unsigned int)-1 / 3`.

Comment: это из уравнения `x*4+1==x` => `x = -1 / 3`. А другие маски так пашут?

Comment: @AlexGlebe Ну, от маски зависит. :)

Comment: Конечно, на настоящий момент, `unsigned int` и `uintmax_t` всегда, или почти всегда совпадают. Но для `uint128_t`, буде такой встретится, не очень. Или для типов (компиляторов) вне стандарта.

Comment: @Serge3leo В смысле? Для GCC-шного `__uint128_t` работает.

Comment: Так пашут любые маски для типов в которых чётное число бит. Круто!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , наверное  вот так работает: `(__uint128_t)-1 / 3`, а  не так, как в вашем ответе написано. Да, ещё, строго переносимо будет же: `(~(T)0)/3`, где T - требуемый тип, впрочем компьютер для которого именно так обязательно, надо ещё поискать.

Comment: @Serge3leo Ааа. Подразумевалось, что тип надо заменить на свой. Так-то uintmax_t обычно 64-битный, под unsigned long long. А int - 32-битный.

Comment: @Serge3leo, как раз `(unsigned type)-1 / 3` - переносимо для любого типа. А `(~(unsigned short)0)/3` выдаст ноль если `short` короче `int`. Короткие беззнаковые типы в арифметике приводятся к `int` со знаком. Получится `-1 / 3`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, ваша правда, переносимый вариант, рассчитанный не только на дополнительный код, но и на обратный код, должен выглядеть немного иначе: `template<typename U> constexpr U mask5() { return (U)~0 / 3; }`

Comment: @Serge3leo, `(U)-1` также даёт максимальное значение типа для любого `U` при любом представлении отицательных чисел. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion: "if the target type is unsigned, the value `2^b`, where `b` is the number of bits in the target type, is repeatedly subtracted or added to the source value until the result fits in the target type. In other words, unsigned integers implement modulo arithmetic.".

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, сомнительное утверждение, да, гарантированно `0u - 1u == UINT_MAX`, но это немного о другом. Впрочем, можно поднять компилятор C для БЭСМ-6, говорят, был такой.

Comment: @wololo, нужна ваша помощь.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, да, согласен с вами. Результатом преобразования `(U)-1` будет величина `(-1) + (U_MAX+1)`, что равно `U_MAX`. Причём в описании алгоритма подразумевается, что выражение `(-1) + (U_MAX+1)` вычисляется в «честных» вещественных числах, на чём в стандарте языка акцентируется внимание. n1570, 6.3.1.3 / 2 / 60): `The rules describe arithmetic on the mathematical value, not the value of a given type of expression.` Способ представления целых знаковых не влияет на результат такого преобразования.

Comment: @Serge3leo, А вот конструкция `(U)~0` переносимой не является. В обратном коде выражение `~0` равно отрицательному нулю. И результатом преобразования `(U)отрицательный_ноль` будет ноль. Более того, реализация может не поддерживать отрицательные нули, и тогда результатом выражения `~0` будет trap representation, что вызывает неопределённое поведение. Ну, а вообще уже малость поздновато учитывать обратный/прямой код, т.к. начиная с C++20 и C23 поддерживается только дополнительный код.

Comment: @wololo, спасибо!

Comment: @wololo, насчёт `(U)отрицательный_ноль` это Вас, конечно, занесло. Вы, вероятно, более менее разумно ссылаетесь на примечание (60), по которому при вычислении выражения `(U)~0` нет места представлению целых чисел со знаком, т.е. из идеального математического выражения `~0` сразу получается значение беззнакового типа `U`. P.S. А в вопросах переносимости на исторические платформы БЭСМ-6 и прочие, всякие там новомодные требования не при делах.

Comment: @Serge3leo, Что не так с отрицательным нулём?

Comment: @wololo, с ним всё так, но согласно примечанию (60) его при вычислении `(U)~0` не возникает, т.к. из идеального математического выражения `~0` сразу получается значение беззнакового типа `U`.

Comment: @Serge3leo, выражение `(U)~0` вычисляется в несколько этапов. Сперва применяется оператор `~`. Он инвертирует каждый бит нулевого значения типа `int`. Итоговое значение такой инверсии зависит от способа представления знаковых целых. И отрицательный ноль может запросто получиться. n1570, 6.2.6.2 / 3: `If the implementation supports negative zeros, they shall be generated only by: — the &, |, ^, ~, <<, and >> operators with operands that produce such a value; ...`. И только потом, к результату инверсии применяется алгоритм приведения типа, который работает в идеальных математических числах.

Answer (score 5):

Воспользуемся тем, что в реальной жизни

1. Размер байта — 8 бит.
2. Размеры целочисленных типов в байтах — степени двойки.

Если это не так, можно пользоваться ответом gbg :)

```
template<unsigned_integral T>
consteval T mask2()
{
    T mask = 0x55;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i < sizeof(T); i*=2)
        mask |= mask << i*8;
    return mask;
}
```

Все ж таки O(log N):), где N — размер типа.

Bычисляется, как и у gbg, во время компиляции — https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/78EaTqzKK

Answer (score 3):

С использованием `constexpr`-функции:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

template <typename T> 
T constexpr mask101() 
{
    T ret = 0;
    for(T mask=1;mask;mask<<=2)
    {
        ret|=mask;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() 
{
    constexpr auto test = mask101<size_t>();
    cout << std::hex <<"0x" << test << endl;
    cout << std::hex <<"0x" << mask101<int32_t>() << endl;
    cout << std::hex <<"0x" << mask101<uint16_t>() << endl;
    cout << std::hex <<"0x" << int(mask101<int8_t>()) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
0x5555555555555555
0x55555555
0x5555
0x55
```

[Код на ideone](https://ideone.com/sE0X3S)

Answer (score 3):

Маска может быть представлена в виде суммы *4<sup>0</sup> + 4<sup>1</sup> + ... + 4<sup>k</sup>*. По формуле суммы геометрической прогрессии эта сумма равна *(4<sup>k+1</sup> - 1) / 3*.

Если в беззнаковом типе чётное число бит, его максимальное значение есть *2<sup>2k</sup> - 1*. Что равно *4<sup>k</sup> - 1*. Если это число поделить на три, получится нужная маска. Например, для `unsigned` вычислите `UINT_MAX / 3`.

Программа на `C` строит маски переносимым образом. Максимальные значения типов получаются как приведение `-1` к беззнаковому типу. Ещё одно приведение нужно чтобы значения типов короче `unsigned` были так же короткими. Иначе получается тип `unsigned` со значением маски `unsigned short` или `unsigned char`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MASK(type) ((type)((type)-1 / 3))

int main() {
    printf("0x%hhx\n", MASK(unsigned char     ));
    printf("0x%hx\n" , MASK(unsigned short    ));
    printf("0x%x\n"  , MASK(unsigned          ));
    printf("0x%lx\n" , MASK(unsigned long     ));
    printf("0x%llx\n", MASK(unsigned long long));
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror mask.c && ./a.out 
> 0x55
> 0x5555
> 0x55555555
> 0x5555555555555555
> 0x5555555555555555
> ```

То же самое на `C++`:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> constexpr T mask() { return static_cast<T>(-1) / 3; }

int main() {
    std::cout << std::hex;
    std::cout << static_cast<unsigned>(mask<unsigned char     >()) << '\n';
    std::cout <<                       mask<unsigned short    >()  << '\n';
    std::cout <<                       mask<unsigned          >()  << '\n';
    std::cout <<                       mask<unsigned long     >()  << '\n';
    std::cout <<                       mask<unsigned long long>()  << '\n';
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror mask.cpp && ./a.out 
> 55
> 5555
> 55555555
> 5555555555555555
> 5555555555555555
> ```

Но что делать если на вашем компьютере есть типы с нечётным числом бит? Например пятибайтовое целое и девять бит в байте. Придётся сделать ещё один шаг:

```
#define DRAFT_MASK(type) ((type)((type)-1 / 3))
#define ODD_BITS(type) ((DRAFT_MASK(type) & 1) ^ 1)
#define MASK(type) ((type)(DRAFT_MASK(type) << ODD_BITS(type) | 1))
```

`DRAFT_MASK` - маска старого образца. Если число бит нечётно, то получится

*(2<sup>2k+1</sup> - 1) / 3 = (2·4<sup>k</sup> - 1) / 3 = (2(4<sup>k</sup> - 1) + 1) / 3 = 2((4<sup>k</sup> - 1) / 3) + 1 / 3*.

Левое слагаемое - удвоенная маска. Правое слагаемое округляется до нуля - деление целочисленное. Получилась маска выделяющая нечётные биты.

Конструкция `ODD_BITS(type)` равна единице если число бит в типе нечётное - проверяется младший бит маски. В этом случае старую маску надо сдвинуть на разряд влево и добавить младший бит. Что и делает `MASK`. Если число бит чётно, результат `MASK` не отличается от `DRAFT_MASK`.

Как обзаведусь соответствующим железом, обязательно потестирую.

Answer (score 2):

В Си помогает создавать константы двойная компиляция. Пример в `gcc` :

> gcc makemask.c -o makemask && makemask > mask.h

Пишем шаблоном, используя размер типа :

```
# define MAKECONST( T , N ) { \
  printf ( "%s const %s = 0x" , ( # T ) , ( N ) ) ; \
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < sizeof ( T ) ; ++ i ) \
    printf ( "%x" , 0x55 ) ; \
  puts ( " ;" ) ; \
}

# include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  MAKECONST ( unsigned short int , "ushort_mask" ) ;
  MAKECONST ( unsigned int , "uint_mask" ) ;
  fflush ( stdout ) ;
}
```

получаем хедер : `mask.h`

```
unsigned short int const ushort_mask = 0x5555 ;
unsigned int const uint_mask = 0x55555555 ;
```

Comment: Месье знает толк...

Answer (score 2):

Имея значения для степеней двойки это можно посчитать без циклов :

```
template<unsigned long long x_index>
constexpr auto pow2{2ull * pow2<x_index - 1ull>};

template<>
constexpr auto pow2<0ull>{1ull};

template<typename x_Integer>
constexpr x_Integer odd_mask{(pow2<sizeof(x_Integer) * 8ull> - 1ull) / 3ull};

static_assert(0x55u == odd_mask<unsigned char>);
static_assert(0x5555u == odd_mask<unsigned short>);
static_assert(0x55555555u == odd_mask<unsigned int>);
static_assert(0x5555555555555555u == odd_mask<unsigned long long>);
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27template%3Cunsigned+long+long+x_index%3E%0Aconstexpr+auto+pow2%7B2ull+*+pow2%3Cx_index+-+1ull%3E%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3C%3E%0Aconstexpr+auto+pow2%3C0ull%3E%7B1ull%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+x_Integer%3E%0Aconstexpr+x_Integer+odd_mask%7B(pow2%3Csizeof(x_Integer)+*+8ull%3E+-+1ull)+/+3ull%7D%3B%0A%0Astatic_assert(0x55u+%3D%3D+odd_mask%3Cunsigned+char%3E)%3B%0Astatic_assert(0x5555u+%3D%3D+odd_mask%3Cunsigned+short%3E)%3B%0Astatic_assert(0x55555555u+%3D%3D+odd_mask%3Cunsigned+int%3E)%3B%0Astatic_assert(0x5555555555555555u+%3D%3D+odd_mask%3Cunsigned+long+long%3E)%3B%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1500,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wconversion+-Wpedantic%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+15.0.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+15.0.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)