# Переполнение в 16-ти битной архитектуре. Код на с

Tags: c, переполнение

Задача такая: вывести все числа в пятой степени до максимального unsigned int.
Я подключила библиотеку и получила верный ответ, но при проверке лабораторной она не засчитывается, так как *"Ваше решение подходит только для 32 бит. Нужно переделать это на логику переполнения целочисленной переменной, чтобы отрабатывало для любой архитектуры"*.

Что это такое и как с этим бороться? Якобы предложенное решение не подходит для 16-ти бит.
Использовать `<stdint.h>` нельзя!!!!

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main()

{
    unsigned base = UINT_MAX;
    char u = ' ';
    int i = 0;
    
    while (i < 85) {
        
        base = i*i*i*i*i;
        
        printf("%u%c", base, u); 
        
        i++;    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Поменять тип у ```base``` с ```unsigned``` на ```unsigned long long```? Будет 64 бита (для большинства современных архитектур), при этом без ```stdint.h```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***NB*** Это решение хорошо работает для размеров целого в 16, 32, 64 бита. Но не для всех. Ниже решение сложнее, но полностью корректное.

Печатайте числа пока не произойдет переполнение. О переполнении вы узнаете по  тому что следующая пятая степень стала меньше предыдущей. Этот трюк работает не всегда, но нам везёт, для 16, 32 и 64 битов он работает:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned prev_i5 = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; ; ++i) {
        unsigned i5 = i * i * i * i * i;
        if (i5 < prev_i5) {
            break;
        }
        prev_i5 = i5;
        printf(" %u", i5); 
    }
    printf("\n"); 
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion temp.c
>
> +~/desk/stackoverflow $ ./a.out 
>  0 1 32 243 1024 3125 7776 16807 32768 59049 100000 161051 248832 371293 537824 759375 1048576 1419857 1889568 2476099 3200000 4084101 5153632 6436343 7962624 9765625 11881376 14348907 17210368 20511149 24300000 28629151 33554432 39135393 45435424 52521875 60466176 69343957 79235168 90224199 102400000 115856201 130691232 147008443 164916224 184528125 205962976 229345007 254803968 282475249 312500000 345025251 380204032 418195493 459165024 503284375 550731776 601692057 656356768 714924299 777600000 844596301 916132832 992436543 1073741824 1160290625 1252332576 1350125107 1453933568 1564031349 1680700000 1804229351 1934917632 2073071593 2219006624 2373046875 25355253762706784157 2887174368 3077056399 3276800000 3486784401 3707398432 3939040643 4182119424
> ```

Как я уже сказал, решение выше не работает для некоторых размеров `unsigned`. Таких размеров четыре: *6*, *7*, *11* и *12* бит. Для всех остальных работает, для этих нет.

Полностью корректное решение проверяет переполнение перед каждым умножением:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned last = (unsigned)-1;
    printf("0"); 
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < last; ++i) {
        unsigned limit = last / i;
        unsigned p = i;
        if (p > limit) break;
        p *= i;
        if (p > limit) break;
        p *= i;
        if (p > limit) break;
        p *= i;
        if (p > limit) break;
        p *= i;
        printf(" %u", p); 
    }
    printf("\n"); 
}
```

Comment: святой человек, спасибо большое!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Да, но... "*чтобы отрабатывало для **любой** архитектуры*". Берем архитектуру с 12 битами Выводим 1, 32, 243, 1024, 1077, 1632... Каждое новое значение больше предыдущего, нет?

Comment: @Harry, вот что за вредный характер. Конечно есть размеры слов для которых переполнение пятой степени не даёт убывание. Это вообще случайное (хотя и довольно вероятное) везение. На всех человеческих размерах трюк прокатывает. Полное корректное решение куда сложнее.

Comment: Да, я вам соврал, конечно, не 12, а 11 битов... Кстати, вы тоже можете проявить вредность :) — посмотрите мой вариант — просто интересно, чего я не увидел?

Comment: @Harry, не соврали. Не работают 6, 7, 11, 12.

Comment: Ошибка. При умножении разрядность числа всегда увеличивается, и проверка сравнением может не сработать. Нужно использовать тип большей разрядности, и проверять на ноль старшую половину результата.

Comment: @AVI-crakHome, приведите пример когда происходит ошибка. Использовать тип большей разрядности - хороший совет, когда такой тип есть. А если типа большей разрядности нет?

Comment: stanislav-volodarskiy - легко https://godbolt.org/z/EKrxzEE1W  - строка 244. Выполняется проверка 64бит числа на переполнение при умножении и сложении. В Си тип uint128_t является опцией для архитектур которые его поддерживают. Но мне его не досталось. По этому операции выполняются буквально, над каждой частью числа с результатом в 64 бита. Вторая часть числа даёт возможность проверки при умножении, так как получается 96бит число.

Answer (score 1):

В связи с тем, что на 11 (соврал в комментарии...) битах фокус с отслеживанием "следующая степень меньше предыдущей" не прокатывает, предлагаю сначала найти размер `unsigned`, типа

```
int main()
{
    unsigned p = 0;
    p = ~p;
    int bits = 0;
    while(p) {++bits; p >>= 1; }
    for(unsigned n = 0; n < pow(2.,bits/5.); ++n)
        cout << n << "   " << n*n*n*n*n << endl;
}
```

Критика приветствуется!

Comment: Для максимального значения типа лучше использовать `(unsigned)-1`. Обсуждали раньше.

Comment: Рабочий вариант.

Comment: Я бы так считал: `n <= pow(p, 1./5.)`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy *лучше использовать (unsigned)-1. Обсуждали раньше* наверное, я пропустил, не помню. Если покажете, где, буду признателен. В моем варианте меня, собственно, смущают приведения типов (а вдруг такая архитектура, где приведение и возведение в степень приведут к проблеме — пусть не для 5 степени, но для какой-то иной задачи...)

Comment: [Обсуждение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1473279/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0-0x55555555-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc/1473434#comment2638311_1473359). Приведение к `double` не думаю что что-то испортит. Есть вопросы к точности `pow`, их можно решить только проверкой. Проверка покажет что всё ОК и точности хватает.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Посмотрел обсуждение. В принципе, что-то такого типа я и представлял, и именно поэтому написал `unsigned p = 0; p = ~p;`, а не типа `unsigned p = ~0;` — чтобы гарантированно получить строчку единиц.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (i < 85)
```

85 в 5 степени - потолок для 32 бит, то есть, больше в строку из 32 клеток 2-битного числа не записать. У 16-битной системы потолок значительно ниже - 65 535. А это значит, что программа упрётся в потолок уже на 9-ой степени, после чего выдаст ошибку.

По-видимому, требуется добавить проверку на тип архитектуры - 16 бит, 32 или 64. В вашем случае, судя по описанию, будет достаточно такого:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main()

{
    unsigned base = UINT_MAX;
    char u = ' ';
    int i = 0;

    int limit;

    if (base < 4294967295)
        limit = 85;
    if (base < 65535)
        limit = 9;

    while (i < limit) {
    
        base = i*i*i*i*i;
    
        printf("%u%c", base, u); 
    
        i++;    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: и вам большое спасибо за объяснение, хоть что-то стало понятно!